# Using TinyMCE rich text editor - how to modify the textbox size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, textarea

I just implemented the TinyMCE rich text editor on my site, and it is actually pretty awesome, but I do have 2 questions.

On this page for example: http://www.problemio.com/add_problem.php

1) What is the "Path p" text at the bottom of the text area? It doesn't make sense and I am not sure how to change it.

2) How do I make the default text area taller?  I changed the page's HTML to this:

```
<textarea name="problem_blurb" cols="60" rows="9" id="problem_blurb"></textarea>
```

But changing the rows parameter does not seem to alter the height of the text area.  Is there a way to change the text area height? I looked at the JS from the TinyMCE package, but its condensed and unreadable, so I am wondering whether there is an easier way to change the height of the text area.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

1. Path `p` means that you're inside a paragraph (html tag p). The path will show you where you are writing inside the rich text (So if you see `div p` means that you're inside a `p` which is inside a `div`)
2. Change the `rows` attribute will change the height. Try to change it to 15 and you'll see the difference.

Comment: I changed it to have more rows, but the rows attritute is getting over-written by the TinyMCE defaults I think.  Any idea how to get around it?

Answer (score 2):

1) The path is the current HTML element you're in, while editing. It means you're writing inside of a `<p>...</p>` (normal paragraph) element.

2) You have to use CSS width and height params. You could do something like:

```
<textarea name="problem_blurb" id="problem_blurb"
style="width: 500px; height: 300px;">
</textarea>
```

Note that if you have enabled the resizable mode in TinyMCE, it might has saved the current size and, then, ignore the CSS-set value. To be able to see your edits, clear your browser's cache and cookies.

Comment: Thanks, I just changed the width and height to pixels, but I think it gets over-written by the JavaScript of the TinyMCE.  It didn't quite work.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Answered by Alf and AurelioDeRosa already. This is a very nice feature.

**2)** You can set the height and width of your tinymce editor using the [width](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3awidth) and height tinymce config parameter.